# manipulating data of object passed by reference to another class

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have a manager class and it contains two classes A and B.
Class A has some information that can change very frequently (say @ 30 fps) over the period, and class B wants to use updated information all the time.

So I wrapped the information required from class A inside a class C and passed a reference of C obj to B using my manager class.

```
class A{
  public C cObj = new C()
  class C{
     public int info1;
     public int info2;
  }
}

class B{
  C obj;
  void setCObj(C ref){
    obj = ref;
  }
}

class Manager{
  bObj.setCObj(aObj.cObj);
}
```

now any changes made in C obj by A will be reflected in B. But I want only A to be able to write info in cObj and not B. how can I do this. Are there any downfalls in passing data this way to another class.

Comment: I would suggest to existing design pattern [Publisher/Subscriber Pattern](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/pranayamr/publisher-or-subscriber-pattern-with-event-or-delegate-and-e/)

Comment: Have a look at [event and delegates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/), they follow the observer pattern, which covers your purposes

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski  and Prakash I studied both the approaches. both seem good, but I will still be giving away the reference of obj C to B in both of these approaches. So B will be able to write that info. Is it possible to let only A manipulate C and no other classes? I don't want to create multiple objects of C as the info inside it is being changed very fast.